# How to inject a module into a class using Typescript and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module

I'm developing in nodeJS + Typescript. I have a OO background and I want to benefit from nodejs modules, but I'm struggling to mix them with classes that are not supposed to be modules.

This is what I'm trying to do:

**foo.ts (module)**

```
import http = require("http")

export class Foo {
    public fooMethod() : number { ... }
}
```

**bar.ts (not supposed to be a module)**

```
namespace Ns {
    export class Bar {
        constructor(private foo: Foo) { ... } //"Foo" is not being found by the intellisense
        public barMethod() : number { 
            return this.foo.fooMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

**server.js (node startup file)**

```
var Foo = import("./foo");

var foo = new Foo();
foo.configure(...)     //Configure foo before inject it into bar

var bar = new Ns.Bar(foo)
```

---

Issues I'm facing when Trying to structure the code like this :

1. **Bar** can't see **Foo**. I tried to add a reference to the file, but it didn't work.
2. It "worked" when I imported ./foo, but when I do that **Bar** can't see other exported types in other files that are defined on the same namespace (even if I write the full name of the type, i.e. include the namespace, it still can't see it).
3. So I removed the namespace **Ns** in **Bar** and I could see other types when I typed its name with the namespace. But now **Bar** is a module and I It feels like my constructor injection smells, since Foo is imported and I can instantiate it directly.

---

I don't want to force my standards. I want to know what is the right approach for what I am trying to do. The struggle makes me feel that I'm obligated to redesign and go full modules when developing nodejs applications. Is that right?

In case that I should go full modules, how should I manage dependency injection?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fully leverage power of **OOP** (or better to say [Interface-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming) or **Protocol-oriented programming**) you should use `interface Foo` to hide using of specific implementation `MyFoo` by `Bar` class.

Foo.ts

```
export interface Foo {
  fooMethod(): number;
}
```

MyFoo.ts

```
export class MyFoo {
  fooMethod(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Bar.ts

```
import {Foo} from './Foo'

export class Bar {
  constructor(private foo: Foo) {}

  barMethod(): number {
    return this.foo.fooMethod();
  }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
import {Boo} from './Boo'
import {MyFoo} from './MyFoo'

const result = new Boo(new MyFoo()).barMethod();
```

Personally I do not recommend to use namespaces. You can read more about namespaces and modules [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).

Comment: I see your point. This approach works well and it really seems like the recommended one. However, in a first look this pattern makes me feel that if I work with many small cohesive classes (each class in a separate file) and many injection levels I could run into some sort of "import hell". Would you know if that is a real concern?

Comment: You will have many small modules (classes) and each of them will depend on a number of other modules injected as interfaces (as `class Bar` depends on `interface Foo`). And the smaller this number is, the lower your modules are coupled and the better your software is designed.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you again. So, I can (1) create interfaces for a module and have the drawback of having interfaces even when I intend to have one single implementation for it, or (2) bypass the interface and import and reference the concrete type to leverage intellisense, but having the drawback of loading the type into the scope of Bar, even not intending to instantiate it. Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: Yes. Also if you write tests for your software then ideally you have at least 2 implementations for each interface - one or more real implementations and one or more fake implementations used for testing classes that depends on these interfaces.